# Error while running file in twilio

Tags: php, twilio

[image]

Hello all i am working on twilio api using php.while uploading my file i got an
error,can anyone please help me out from this.fast response is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want us to help, atleast post your code

Comment: Would be better to know what error you have.

Comment: $capability = new ClientToken($accountSid, $authToken);
//$capability = new ClientToken($accountSid, $authToken);
$capability->allowClientOutgoing($appSid);
$capability->allowClientIncoming('Amit');
  $token = $capability->generateToken();

//echo $token;
//print_R($token);
echo "<br>";
//echo $token;
?><?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit']))
{
 $response = new Twiml;
 $dial = $response->dial();
    $dial->conference('Room 123', array(
        'startConferenceOnEnter' => True,
        'endConferenceOnExit' => True
    ));

Comment: @MedMekss above is my code